# Saving and retrieving multiple cached json/txt data files

Tags: data, json, caching, indexing

I am working on some numerical programming and need to generate the results for a model given a variety of input parameters. Since the model takes a while to run, I was planning to save the data to some sort of text/json file, so that I can just load the results later.

However, since I will end up generating a bunch of different model result files--like at least 100, I was trying to figure out the best way to do this.

I thought about creating a naming convention for the text files, but that might be cumbersome and cryptic to program and update if there are changes.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to do this in a sustainable and simple way?

Comment: You may want to look into [HDF](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).